# Why does Carol call the police (presumably on herself)?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, spinning-out

In the last episode of season one of "Spinning Out", Carol finds out that her 16-year-old daughter Serena has been seduced by a much older man.

It seems that there are not many proofs about this crime (which would be at best unprofessional conduct/abuse of trust and statutory rape at worst), because they only have a trail of text messages sent to a burner phone, so Carol takes measures in her own hands, goes to the offender, introduces herself and hits him in the head with a baseball bat. Then, she picks up her phone and calls the police reporting an assault.

Ok, I can understand revenge and anger about such mistreatment of her daughter, but why does she call the police on herself? We know that Carol has a bipolar disorder, but at this stage of the plot she seems to manage her condition fairly well - when she is making this call she is very calm and calculated, she even waves to a concerned neighbour who saw this attack and makes sure that that person sees her putting down the bat. Is this some sort of elaborate plan to bring the assailant to justice (other than bash-on-the-head)? In the previous scene, she said that she was going to call the police on him, but this attack would rather hurt her case than help - the offender can always say "both the daughter and mother are crazy!".